# Fetching API and displaying in react-select dropdown

Tags: html, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select and I want to fetch options from api. In the documentation is mostly hard coded data for options which should be displayed. I mapped through array and stored the data into state.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async'
import './Search.css'



class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: '',
    selectedOption: '',
    cleareble: false,
    cars: []
  }    

  componentDidMount() {
        fetch('url')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                cars: [res.cars.make, res.cars.link]
            })
            console.log("hello", this.state.cars)
        })
   }

   handleChange(selectedOption) {
    this.setState({selectedOption});
   }
  render() {
    let options = this.state.cars.map(function (car) {
      return { value: car.make, label: car.make, image: car.link };
    })
  return (
    <div>
<AsyncSelect
  className='select-search'
  value={this.state.inputValue}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  cleareble={this.state.cleareble}
  options={options}
  formatOptionLabel={car => (
    <div className="car-option">
      <img src={car.image} alt="car-image" />
      <span>{car.label}</span>
    </div>
      )}/>
    </div>
  );
}

}

export default Search;
```

But it doesnt display fetched makes and images of cars. These are the error messages appearing:

[image]

And here is the example code of json file from where I'm fetching data from:

`[{"make":"KIA","link":"\/images\/image.jpg"},{"make":"BMW","link":"\/images\/image.jpg"}]`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can improve.

First of all, if your data is in the format you specified, there is no need to `setState` the way you are doing right now as `res` itself is an array of objects. If what you're trying to do is extracting only `make` and `link` property from a complex datasets, you should be mapping through all results.

Secondly, you should bind your `handleChange` or use an arrow function. This is just a Javascript thing so I won't go into much details.

Lastly, if you are using Async Select, you should consider using `defaultOption` instead of `option` to initialize options.

Also I suggest you have a look at `loadOptions` prop instead of having to initialize the options on component mount. This way, fetching is only done when user interacts with the react-select component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async'
import './Search.css'



class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: '',
    selectedOption: '',
    cleareble: false,
    cars: []
  }    

  componentDidMount() {
        fetch('url')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                cars: res
            })
        })
   }

   handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({selectedOption});
   }
  render() {
    let options = this.state.cars.map(function (car) {
      return { value: car.make, label: car.make, image: car.link };
    })
  return (
    <div>
<AsyncSelect
  className='select-search'
  value={this.state.selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  cleareble={this.state.cleareble}
  defaultOptions={options}
  formatOptionLabel={car => (
    <div className="car-option">
      <img src={car.image} alt="car-image" />
      <span>{car.label}</span>
    </div>
      )}/>
    </div>
  );
}

}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Still wont render fetched data from JSON file even when I applied these changes that you mentioned. But it renders hard coded arrays of objects.

Comment: Are you fetching from a custom api route? If so can I see how youre sending the JSON